# Get the current QgsFeature while rendering an Atlas

Tags: pyqgis-3, atlas

I'm building an Atlas generator based on the QGIS Layout engine.
I want to fetch extra data from database based on some attributes of the current feature.

In PyQGIS 2, that was possible with

```py
for i in range(0, atlas.numFeatures()):
   atlas.prepareForFeature(i)
   feat = atlas.feature()  # here I can access any attribute of the current feature
```

I can't find a way to get the same in PyQGIS 3...

```py
atlas = self.layout.atlas()
atlas.setEnabled(True)
atlas.setCoverageLayer(self.loaded_layers_registry['campaign_parcel'])
atlas.setFilterFeatures(True)
atlas.setFilterExpression('Some expression')

atlas.beginRender()
for i in range(0, atlas.count()):
    feature = atlas.??????  # How to get the current feature here????
    current_client = results(GET_CLIENT, [feature['client_id']])
    # Here I want to update the text of a label or whatever....
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(atlas.layout())
    exporter.exportToPdf(os.path.join(export_directory, atlas.currentFilename() + '.pdf'), QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
    atlas.next()

atlas.endRender()
```

Does anyone know a way?

**-- EDIT --**

As @J.Monticolo says in comments there is a way but it seems very ugly to me...

The idea is to use the `featureChanged` signal of `QgsLayoutAtlas` to catch the actual feature. It seems to works pretty well but you need to manually starts the iteration to force the signal to be fired for the first feature.
Then you need to come back to the start. This is the part that seems bad to me...

This is what I use for the moment:

```py
def on_atlas_feature_changed(self, feat):
    self.atlas_feature = feat

def export_cr(self):
    atlas = self.layout.atlas()
    atlas.featureChanged.connect(self.on_atlas_feature_changed)
    atlas.beginRender()
    for i in range(0, atlas.count()):
        if not self.atlas_feature: # self.atlas_feature is initialize to None 
            atlas.next()
            atlas.first() # this step is necessary to fire the featureChanged() signal that give the actual QgsFeature
        epandage_html = self.get_epandage_html(self.atlas_feature['id'])
        txt_epandage = self.layout.itemById('epandage')
        txt_epandage.setText(self.get_epandage_html(self.atlas_feature['id']))
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(atlas.layout())
        exporter.exportToPdf(os.path.join(export_directory, atlas.currentFilename() + '.pdf'), QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
        atlas.next()

    atlas.endRender()
    atlas.featureChanged.disconnect(self.on_atlas_feature_changed)
    self.atlas_feature = None
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `atlas.coverageLayer().getFeature(atlas.currentFeatureNumber())` ?

Comment: Nope, but from my understanding the currentFeatureNumber is more like a counter in the atlas and not the actual id of a feature. I will make a try and let you know, thk's for your comment.

Comment: @J.Monticolo As I expect, the `currentFeatureNumber()` returns the feature number in the atlas (0, then 1, then 2,...) but the not the feature id.

Comment: so, maybe playing with the signal `featureChanged` and catch the current feature, I've no other idea.

Comment: Nice idea! Actually it almost works. But as the signal is only fired when feature **changed**, I miss the first one...

Comment: But maybe you have just to connect the signal and force `atlas.first()` (QgsLayoutAtlas), so the feature will change and you'll capture every features.

Comment: Yes that's what i've done. But It seems very ugly to me....

Comment: But you can always in your code create a property `current_feature` and a method connected to the signal that updates the property each time and then you can always have the atlas feature, no uglyness, just pure PyQt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I reviewed a little your script and below a proposed code :

```py
class MyPyQgisScript(QObject):

    def __init__(self, project_layout: QgsLayout, parent=None):
        super(MyPyQgisScript, self).__init__(parent)
        self._atlas_feature = None
        self.layout = project_layout
        self.atlas = self.layout.atlas()
        # connect the signal to catch the atlas feature
        self.atlas.featureChanged.connect(
            lambda feat: setattr(self.atlas_feature, feat)
        )
        # init atlas_feature
        self.atlas.refreshCurrentFeature()

    @property
    def atlas_feature(self) -> QgsFeature:
        """Project layout Current Atlas feature"""
        return self._atlas_feature

    @atlas_feature.setter
    def atlas_feature(self, feat: QgsFeature) -> None:
        """Sets the atlas feature
        :param feat: the current atlas feature
        """
        if isinstance(feat, QgsFeature):
            self._atlas_feature = feat
        else:
            self._atlas_feature = None

    def export_cr(self) -> None:
        """Exports the atlas to pdf"""
        self.atlas.beginRender()
        for i in range(0, self.atlas.count()):
            epandage_html = self.get_epandage_html(self.atlas_feature["id"])
            txt_epandage = self.layout.itemById("epandage")
            txt_epandage.setText(
                self.get_epandage_html(self.atlas_feature["id"])
            )
            exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(self.atlas.layout())
            exporter.exportToPdf(
                os.path.join(
                    export_directory,
                    f"{self.atlas.currentFilename()}.pdf"),
                    QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
            )
            self.atlas.next()

        self.atlas.endRender()
```

Comment: Thk's for this, it works well and look cleaner!